# Set default starting point on Picker

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

How do I set the starting value to the text "Please Select One" inside the picker. Currently it defaults to the first choice in the array.

This is the state

```
@State var Choioce = 0
```

This is the picker

```
var settings = ["ch1", "ch2", "ch3"]
Picker("Options", selection: $Choioce) {
    Text("Please Select One")
    ForEach(0 ..< settings.count) { index in
        Text(self.settings[index])
            .tag(index)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make selection optional, like below. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var Choioce: Int?               // << here !!
    var settings = ["ch1", "ch2", "ch3"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Selection: \(Choioce == nil ? "<none>" : settings[Choioce!])")
            Picker("Options", selection: $Choioce) {
                Text("Please Select One").tag(Optional<Int>.none)
                ForEach(0 ..< settings.count) { index in
                    Text(self.settings[index])
                        .tag(Optional(index))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tried this the state is not updating anymore. I added `Text("You selected: \(settings[Choioce!])")` to see the live change of the values but it is not updating as it was before turning it into an optional.

Comment: Please see updated, with fix and testing Text added.